# Syntax for displaying one variable in PHP of SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I was practicing making some sort of phonebook for my contacts and I ran into a problem when displaying the information in a table that is dynamically created using PHP. The table displays a row for each type of phone a person posses, for example for the house, cellphone and so on.

For that I made multiple functions that get information out of a database, but then I realized that I cannot think of a way to to return just the one variable I need (the number) because my select is also taking the id of the contact and of the type of phone to retrieve the number.

So my question is: How can I write in the PHP function that I only want to display the field for the phone number (numeroTelefono).

To further illustrate here is mySQL queries and PHP functions:

PHP function that creates the HTML and display the information the query gets:

---

```
function displaySpecificTels(){

if(isset($_POST['pIdC'])){

    $idC = $_POST['pIdC'];


$casa    = getSpecificCasa($idC);
$movil   = getSpecificMovil($idC);
$trabajo = getSpecificTrabajo($idC);
$fax     = getSpecificFax($idC);
$otro    = getSpecificOtro($idC);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($PLACEHOLDER)){
```

Perhaps remove the while and just echo? If so then what do I write where $row was?

```
echo 

    '<table class="tableFormat2 floatLeft">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Casa</th>
                <th>Móvil</th>
                <th>Trabajo</th>
                <th>Fax</th>
                <th>Otro</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>' . $row['casa'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row['movil'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row['trabajo'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row['fax'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row['otro'] . '</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
     </table>';

    }
  }
}
```

SQL example of one of my functions:

```
function getSpecificCasa($idCont){

$id  = 1;

$query = "SELECT bk.idTelefono , bk.idTipoTelefono, bk.numeroTelefono FROM telefono as bk WHERE bk.idTipoTelefono = $id AND bk.idTelefono = $idCont";

$result = do_query($query);

return $result;

}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Do_Query function does this:

```
function do_query($query){
global $db_server;

$result = mysql_query($query , $db_server);

if( !$result)
    die("Falló la sentencia" . mysql_error());

    return $result;
}
```

Would just returning bk.numeroTelefono and then using $result in the PHP that creates the HTML be viable?

Comment: try to display it using var_dump($PLACEHOLDER) to see its structure

Comment: @cake thanks for the edit Mr.Cake!

Comment: @ZarkDev Sorry, I am not quite knowledgeable of programming yet, even less of PHP and SQL so I am not familiar of how that syntax would look on paper. That is the reason why I asked my question originally, for example var_dump where and what?

Comment: @Code Grasshopper: welcome ....

Comment: before your while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($PLACEHOLDER)){ display the result of your query with var_dump($PLACEHOLDER);

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but you might want to consider restructuring your table output so that it's not echoing so much raw html. Instead, create the table in your markup and just echo the values into it. +10 for improving maintainability.

Comment: You're right. I'll just remove all but the tds and use the tbody id to inser them there.